# awk/sed - transforming regex-matches

Tags: awk, transformation, gsub

I want to modify strings which are matching a regular expression. 
Using Awk with gsub, there is "&", which represents the match. Is there a way to modify this "matching value: &" and then passing it to the second parameter of gsub, so that it takes the match, replaces it in a certain way and then replaces it?
Maybe this can be also done with sth like a: sed 's///g' ?

For example: replacing all occurences like "0.123e2" with "12.3"

Comment: What is your question? Can you give an example?

Comment: Is your goal just to fix the format of all floating point numbers (possibly in a file)?

Answer (score 0):

In normal awk You can try something like this to process all numeric values:

```
awk '
  {
    s=""; e = $0
     while (match(e, /(+|-)?[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+e(+|-)?[[:digit:]]+/)) {
      p=substr(e, 1, RSTART-1);
      m=substr(e, RSTART, RLENGTH);
      e=substr(e, RSTART+RLENGTH);
      # Modify mathed data
      s = s p sprintf("%.1f", m);
    }
    print s e
  }' <<XXX
0.123e2 0.234e5
-12298.345e-3 some
0.234 number
XXX
```

Output

```
12.3 23400.0
-12.3 some
0.234 number
```

It searches first occurrence of the RE (now `num.num e num`), then cuts off the leading, matching and trailing strings (`p`, `m`, `e`). Then the matching string (`m`) can be modified (now it is just formatted as `%.1f`). The leading and matching part added to the result string (`s`) and then the trailing part is processed again. If there is no more matching string then the result is printed.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk:

```
$ cat file
foo 0.123e2 bar 0.123e2

$ gawk '{print gensub(/0.(12)(3)e2/,"\\1.\\2","g")}' file
foo 12.3 bar 12.3
```